# Amorçage et démarrage: Est-qu'il y a une différence?

Tags: sens, économie

Dans le livre 'L'État Entrepreneur' de Mariana Mazzucato, paru chez Fayard, l'auteur fait une distinction entre Amorçage et Démarrage qui n'est pas soutenue par leur sens aux dictionnaires que j'ai consultés.

Probablement, il peut s'avérer que la différence soit restreinte au sujet de l'économie, mais je n'ai pas pu la trouver dans mes recherches.

Je vous remercie par avance.

Comment: Quelle distinction faite dans l'ouvrage en question est absente des dictionnaires ?

Comment: Peut-on illustrer à partir d'un extrait ?

Comment: @ZéhontéeBonteuse « Le capital-risque est rare au stade de l'amorçage du développement de l'entreprise, car le risque est beaucoup plus élevé dans cette phase initiale où le potentiel d'une nouvelle idée comme ses conditions technologiques et commerciales sont complètement incertains» Et puis, un tableau avec plusieurs stades de développement d'une start-up est présenté. Deux de ces stades sont "amorçage" et démarrage, mais aucune distinction est faite au-delà d'une potentiel différence dans la chronologie...

Answer (score 5):

Sans plus de précisions, je dirais qu'amorcer précède démarrer.

L'amorçage consiste à établir les conditions qui permettent au démarrage de s'effectuer avec succès.

Comment: Pouvez-vous partager quelques liens soutenant votre réponse, s'il vous plaît? Merci ;)

Comment: Ma réponse est générale. Difficile de répondre plus précisément sans savoir ce qu'il y a dans ce livre mais je pensais par exemple à l'amorçage d'une pompe avant de la démarrer, l'amorce d'un dialogue qui précède un éventuel vrai dialogue. À l'inverse, on désamorce une bombe pour l'empêcher d'exploser.